# How to resolve Sitecore.Client conflict on Sitecore 8.2 Update-5

Tags: publishing

I am trying to use an [ASPX page](https://github.com/adoprog/Sitecore-Deployment-Helpers/blob/master/Publish.aspx) to publish my master database to the web database.

The page contains this code:

```
PublishManager.Republish(Sitecore.Client.ContentDatabase, new Database[] { web }, LanguageManager.GetLanguages(master).ToArray(), Sitecore.Context.Language);
```

At compile time, an error is thrown saying:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0434: The namespace 'Sitecore.Client' in '...\Sitecore.Client.LicenseOptions.DLL' conflicts with the type 'Sitecore.Client' in '...\Sitecore.Kernel.DLL'
```

And later in the error, there is:

```
Publish.aspx(27,56): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ContentDatabase' does not exist in the namespace 'Sitecore.Client' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I know that the Sitecore.Kernel assembly contains the property used in the code above:

```
namespace Sitecore
{
    public static Database ContentDatabase
    {
        get
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked online and tried a few things that did not help:

1. Add the Sitecore.Kernel assembly in a web.config file. Maybe I did not add it the correct way. I do not know.
2. Change the above code to specifically tell the compiler I want the "Client" static class reference with:

   ```
   var sitecoreClient = Sitecore.Client;
   PublishManager.Republish(sitecoreClient.ContentDatabase, new Database[] { web }, LanguageManager.GetLanguages(master).ToArray(), Sitecore.Context.Language);
   ```
3. Add a namespace reference to "Sitecore"

   ```
   <%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore" %>
   ```

I am out of ideas and I do not understand how to resolve this error. I am reaching for your help. How would you solve this conflict?

Thanks

Comment: You are publishing from Master to Web? If yes, why not use master database instead of ContentDatabase. Something like this: `PublishManager.Republish(master, new Database[] { web }, LanguageManager.GetLanguages(master).ToArray(), Sitecore.Context.Language);`

Comment: That makes perfect sense and it works. Thanks for the idea! I somehow tried to make the code work as written by its author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are publishing from `master` to `web`, instead of using the ContentDatabase you can use master database directly.

From the code you shared:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Sitecore.Context.SetActiveSite("shell");
  using (new SecurityDisabler())
  {
      DateTime publishDate = DateTime.Now;
      Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
      Sitecore.Data.Database web = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");
      PublishManager.Republish(Sitecore.Client.ContentDatabase, new Database[] { web }, LanguageManager.GetLanguages(master).ToArray(), Sitecore.Context.Language);
  }
}
```

Just change the line for Republish Method to

```
PublishManager.Republish(master, new Database[] { web }, LanguageManager.GetLanguages(master).ToArray(), Sitecore.Context.Language);
```